# Getting a GCM registration ID on a desktop client

Tags: android, python, google-cloud-messaging, xmpppy

I am trying to register a client python script on a desktop so it can act like its an adroid device to receive data. I am using xmpppy, and I am able to talk with the connection server, but I need to request a registration id based of my sender ID. From Android, its a simple function call, but how can I accomplish this on the Desktop?